# Формирование и трансляция видео-потока в asp.net

Tags: asp.net, видео, streaming

Задача: захватить видео с экрана рабочего стола и транслировать по локальной сети в реальном времени. Использую asp.net. (это важно)
Захватить экран не проблема. Правда получается не видео, а поток кадров. 
Каждый кадр я сжимаю в Jpeg и получаю массив байт.
Эти масивчики уже можно стримить. Но вот как?

У меня есть такой вариант, и он работает, НО...

```
    public void ScreenCapture()
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=--myboundary";
        Response.Expires = 0;
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

        var ae = new ASCIIEncoding();
        while (Response.IsClientConnected)
        {
            byte[] data = getNextFrame();
            try
            {
                var boundary = ae.GetBytes("\r\n--myboundary\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\nContent-Length:"
                    + data.Length + "\r\n\r\n");
                Response.OutputStream.Write(boundary, 0, boundary.Length);
                Response.OutputStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                Response.Flush();
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }
        Response.End();
    }
```

Получается быстро обновляемая картинка, скорость низкая, другими словами слайд шоу примерно 5-10 кадров\сек.

Я же хочу получить приемлемое качество. В идеале запихать этот поток в html тег  так как он поддерживает буферизацию по умолчанию, что само по себе повысит плавность видео.

Даже не проблема сделать на js парсер с буфером, и отображать видео вручную, но я не понимаю несколько моментов.

Вопросы: 
Я вот не могу найти и понять, чем поток последовательных кадров отличается от видео, если каждый кадр пропущен через компрессор?
Если есть отличие, а я чувствую что есть, как мне из этих кадров сделать настоящий видео поток?
Каким способом реализовать отправку?
Html тег  без проблем читает видео из файла, но как заставить его читать из памяти?
Ну и в целом жду советов по теме, спасибо.

P.S. Просмотр через браузер обязательное условие.

Comment: а можно вместо картинки организовать оформленный код?

Comment: Поправил. 1234567

Comment: У вас каждый кадр - отдельная полноценная картинка. Между тем во многих современных видеоформатах кадр является лишь диффом между текущей и предыдущей картинкой. Соответственно, объем намного меньше, фпс выше.

Comment: Как мне из этих отдельных картинок сформировать видео, не записывая в файл? И как заставить базовый html видео плеер тянуть поток не из файла а из памяти?